# Why its showing undefined ? while I have data in firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatable, datatables

The datatable row showing undefine instead of the data that I have in the firebase database even I try to put random data in datatable HTML file but still it shows undefined

[My Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l3Bc.png) 
and my data is also coming from the firebase as you can see console

[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVmxw.png)

MIne HTML code:

```
  <body>
    <table id="user_data" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>USN</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Password</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>

         <tbody id="table-body-pengguna">
             <tr>
                <td id="USN"></td>
                <td id="email"></td>
                <td id="name"></td>
                <td id="password"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Mine JS code:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 firebase.analytics();

 $(document).ready(function() {

      var table = $('#user_data').DataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          orderCellsTop: true,
          fixedHeader: true,
          targets: -1,
          className: 'dt-body-right',
          hover: 1

      });

   });

  firebase.database().ref('StudentID').get().then(function(snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.exists()) {
             console.log(snapshot.val());
             USN = snapshot.val().UserUSN;
             Email = snapshot.val().Useremail;
             Name = snapshot.val().Username;
             Password = snapshot.val().Userpassword;

             document.getElementById("USN").innerHTML = USN;
             document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = Email;
             document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = Name;
             document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = Password;

         } else {
            console.log(data.val());
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error);
       });
```

Comment: do `console.log(snapshot.val().UserUSN)` see if this showing you right value or undefined

Comment: using this it is showing undefined but I want to know why... why it showing the data when using console.log(snapshot.val()) and showing undefined while console.log(snapshot.val().UserUSN)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to add data to datatable

var table = $('#user_data').DataTable({
"bFilter": true
});

```
firebase.database().ref('StudentID').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var dataSet = [snapshot.val().UserUSN, snapshot.val().Useremail, 
        snapshot.val().Username, snapshot.val().Userpassword];
         table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
   });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Read Functions require function which runs when a child is detected in your reference and then runs the code which retrieves your data from Realtime Database.

Use this code:

```
firebase.database().ref('StudentID').on('child_added', (data) =>{
    var USN = data.val().UserUSN;
    var Email = data.val().Useremail;
    var Name = data.val().Username;
    var Password = data.val().Userpassword;
    document.getElementById("USN").innerHTML = USN;
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = Email;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = Name;
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = Password;
})
```

Comment: while using  '.on' then it is showing only the first data of the database and while using '.once' it is showing only the last data of the database in the datatable

Comment: could you please share a screenshot for better understanding